# Java 8 Date API - Get total number of weeks in a month

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin, java-8, date

I have a Kotlin function to get the total number of weeks in a month

**Code**

```
fun getTotalWeeksInMonth(instant: Instant): Int {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = Date.from(instant)

    return calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)
}
```

However this is using a mix of the old Java date/time APIs (`Date` and `Calendar`) and the new APIs (`Instant`)

How would I achieve the same result, using just the new APIs?

Comment: "defined as such" ... you haven't defined anything. What do you want? What is "the total number of weeks in a month"?

Comment: @Michael For example, January 2019 spans 5 weeks, but I don't want to find that out using deprecated APIs

Comment: @deHaar That's exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: @series0ne Well, what do you define as a week? UK uses Monday as the start of the week, US uses Sunday.

Comment: @Michael so let's say you wanted to find the last Sunday in January, 2019. That would be the 27th. But let's say you wanted to find the 5th Sunday in January, 2019. That date doesn't exist because there are only 4 Sundays in January, 2019. However the same does not apply for March 2019, because there are five Sundays, so I need a function that determines how many weeks are in the month? - Unless you can think of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this pair of lines:

```
YearMonth currentYearMonth = 
    YearMonth.now( 
        ZoneId.systemDefault() 
    )
;
int weeks = 
    currentYearMonth
    .atEndOfMonth()
    .get(
        WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth()
    )
;
```

Comment: No need to use getters for the year and month, you can just do `YearMonth.from(date)`

Comment: Also, `weekOfMonth` comes with a large number of caveats.

Comment: @Michael I edited the code. Actually none of the `LocalDate` code was needed. We can capture the current `YearMonth` with [`YearMonth.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-).

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the "week of month" of last day of this month, in java:

```
static int getTotalWeeksInMonth(Instant instant) {
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = localDate.withDayOfMonth(localDate.lengthOfMonth());
    int lastWeekOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth());
    return lastWeekOfMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this fits you, be careful about what `Zone` you are actually passing, and about `WeekFields.ISO`, in some regions it may work fine, but in others it may not:

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();

ZonedDateTime zonedNow = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime monthEnd = zonedNow.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());

System.out.println(monthEnd.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an `Instant` I would convert it to date first:

```
val date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Then go with either

```
YearMonth.from(date).atEndOfMonth().get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)
```

or

```
YearMonth.from(date).atEndOfMonth().get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfMonth())
```

Complete example:

```
fun getTotalWeeksInMonth(instant: Instant): Int {
    val date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault())
    return YearMonth.from(date).atEndOfMonth().get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH)
}
```